# How does H264 decoder know which frame to reference

Tags: video, h.264

In the case the reference frame is not the previous frame, for example when LTR is used, or the previous frame is invalidated, how does the decoder know which frame to reference? Is this information stored in the bitstream? I looked the NAL spec, but didn't find where the reference frame ID being specified in the bitstream.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the reference fames are in macroblocks.